# What API to use for Offline Chrome App

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app, offlineapps

I want to develop an offline chrome application.

As in offline app SQL is not available , so what API can serve the following purpose.

=>Large Storage

=>Efficient method to set and get values

=>Fast

=>Secured (user cannot temper the data)

Confused between IndexDB and File System API

I have knowledge of web languages and how online apps can store data on server. But don't know much about how to save data offline.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It all depends on your needs.
The Chrome apps have couple of limitations. Because they must to be very fast some [web API's are disabled](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated). You can't use localStorage and webSql for example.

However in apps you have different set of storage options:

- [chrome.storage.local](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-local) - equivalent for localStorage but asynchronous. you can also save/read many objects at once
- [chrome.storage.sync](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/storage#property-sync) - same as above but data are shared between different app instances (on other browser's profiles or machines)
- [web filesystem API](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) - well known web filesystem API that can keep any kind of file in protected, browser storage. User's do not have direct access to this files, only the app have
- extension to the above: [chrome.syncFileSystem](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem) - it works similar to the above but files saved using this API are synced between app's instances (e.g. different machines) using Google Drive as a back-end. However user's can't see synced files in Drive UI because they are hidden.
- [chrome.fileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/fileSystem) - another extension to the web filesystem API and it gives you access to the user's sandboxed local filesystem. You can read from and write to selected by the user locations.
- [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) - quoting the docs: IndexedDB is an API for client-side storage of significant amounts of structured data, which also enables high performance searches of this data using indexes.
- other custom solutions saving data on some server and syncing changes in all instances

You can choose one of above. As I can see you'll probably want to use IndexedDB API. It is not SQL and it is different approach to saving data. If you never use it before try some [sample app](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) first. However it's fast, efficient and combining with [unlimitedStorage permission](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/declare_permissions) also can set large amount of data.

I also suggesting you to read Offline First page in Chrome Apps documentation where are examples of solutions for making an app offline.

Comment: will go with IndexDB because of fast and efficient data saving in form of indexes.

Comment: I can also suggest Dexi Js as a wrapper to the indexeddb. It's not another SQL-like adapter for indexed DB but a wrapper that makes live much easier when using idb as a storage.